# django orm - How to use select_related() on the Foreign Key of a Subclass from its Super Class

Tags: django, inheritance, orm

I've always found the Django orm's handling of subclassing models to be pretty spiffy. That's probably why I run into problems like this one.

Take three models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(A):
    fk_field = models.ForeignKey('C')

class C(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So now you can query the `A` model and get all the `B` models, where available:

```
the_as = A.objects.all()
for a in the_as:
    print a.b.fk_field.field2 #Note that this throws an error if there is no B record
```

The problem with this is that you are looking at a huge number of database calls to retrieve all of the data.

Now suppose you wanted to retrieve a QuerySet of all `A` models in the database, but with all of the subclass records and the subclass's foreign key records as well, using `select_related()` to limit your app to a single database call. You would write a query like this:

```
the_as = A.objects.select_related("b", "b__fk_field").all()
```

One query returns all of the data needed! Awesome.

Except not. Because this version of the query is doing its own filtering, even though `select_related` is not supposed to filter any results at all:

```
set_1 = A.objects.select_related("b", "b__fk_field").all() #Only returns A objects with associated B objects
set_2 = A.objects.all() #Returns all A objects
len(set_1) > len(set_2) #Will always be False
```

I used the django-debug-toolbar to inspect the query and found the problem. The generated SQL query uses an `INNER JOIN` to join the `C` table to the query, instead of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like other subclassed fields:

```
SELECT "app_a"."field1", "app_b"."fk_field_id", "app_c"."field2"
FROM "app_a" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_b" ON ("app_a"."id" = "app_b"."a_ptr_id") 
    INNER JOIN "app_c" ON ("app_b"."fk_field_id" = "app_c"."id");
```

And it seems if I simply change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, then I get the records that I want, but that doesn't help me when using Django's ORM.

Is this a bug in `select_related()` in Django's ORM? Is there any work around for this, or am I simply going to have to do a direct query of the database and map the results myself? Should I be using something like Django-Polymorphic to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug, specifically it seems to be ignoring the nullable nature of the A->B relationship, if for example you had a foreign key reference to B in A instead of the subclassing, that foreign key would of course be nullable and django would use a left join for it. You should probably raise this in the django issue tracker. You could also try using prefetch_related instead of select_related that might get around your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this, but I will wait a while to accept it in hopes that I can get some better answers.

The `INNER JOIN` created by the `select_related('b__fk_field')` needs to be removed from the underlying SQL so that the results aren't filtered by the `B` records in the database. So the new query needs to leave the `b__fk_field` parameter in `select_related` out:

```
the_as = A.objects.select_related('b')
```

However, this forces us to call the database everytime a `C` object is accessed from the `A` object.

```
for a in the_as:
    #Note that this throws an DoesNotExist error if a doesn't have an
    #associated b
    print a.b.fk_field.field2 #Hits the database everytime.
```

The hack to work around this is to get all of the `C` objects we need from the database from one query and then have each `B` object reference them manually. We can do this because the database call that accesses the `B` objects retrieved will have the `fk_field_id` that references their associated `C` object:

```
c_ids = [a.b.fk_field_id for a in the_as] #Get all the C ids
the_cs = C.objects.filter(pk__in=c_ids) #Run a query to get all of the needed C records
for c in the_cs:
    for a in the_as:
        if a.b.fk_field_id == c.pk: #Throws DoesNotExist if no b associated with a
            a.b.fk_field = c
            break
```

I'm sure there's a functional way to write that without the nested loop, but this illustrates what's happening. It's not ideal, but it provides all of the data with the absolute minimum number of database hits - which is what I wanted.

Comment: Is this still an open issue?