# Following subclass relationships with select_related

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a multi-table inheritance schema similar to the following:

```
class NodeData(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, db_index = True)
    value = models.FloatField(default = 0)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=True)

class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    node_tree = models.ForeignKey(NodeTree, db_index = True)
    unique_name = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=True)
    last_updated_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('date last updated', blank=True)

class ConceptNode(Node):
    node_parent = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name="nodeParent", null=True, blank=True)

class DerivedNode(Node):
    node_source = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name="nodeSource")
    node_target = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name="nodeTarget")
```

For performance reasons, I am using select_related(depth = 2) whenever I fetch a large selection of NodeData elements.  However, select_related does not follow relations down to subclasses, so the following code* results in a call to the ConceptNode implementation of myFunction with no pre-fetched data for the ConceptNode object used in that function:

```
nd = NodeData.objects.get(id = 1)
nd.node.conceptnode.myFunction()
```

This makes select_related not so useful, since there are a lot of functions called this way, and they aren't reaping the benefits of the data cached by select_related.

**My question is:** can I get select_related to fetch this information for me, so that each NodeData object I get has both the Node and ConceptNode/DerivedNode instance cached?*

*NOTE: This is actually done using an accessor function model like I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694883/how-does-determining-subclass-through-hasattr-trigger-a-db-query-in-djangos-orm)*

*NOTE: What I'm trying to do is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020813/django-orm-how-to-use-select-related-on-the-foreign-key-of-a-subclass-from-i), but is a bit different because I have multiple subclasses.*

**EDIT**: Thanks to the tip from chris-platt, I found the following does what I need:

```
nd = NodeData.objects.select_related('conceptnode','derivednode').get(id = 1)
nd.node.conceptnode.myFunction()
```

The first line pre-fetches the DerivedNode or ConceptNode instance into the relevant cache object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do something like `ConceptNode.objects.get(...)`, the `Node` instance will be fetched simultaneously so you have the complete data for your instance. However, when you do something like `Node.objects.get(...)` the data from the `ConceptNode`, etc. subclasses is *not* included. To select these, you need to use `select_related(<related_name>)`, and to get multiple subclasses, you just keep adding the `related_name`s as a comma-delimited list, e.g.:

```
Node.objects.select_related('nodeParent', 'nodeSource', 'nodeTarget')
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - your response got me moving in the right direction.  Providing the implicitly defined related_name fields defined for multi-table inheritance works.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a slight misunderstanding here on how `select_related` works. It doesn't work for all relationships, it works for foreign key or one-to-one relationships -- where the related data is a single record and where the original query can be modified with a join to get it. So this example does not work:

```
nd = NodeData.objects.get(id = 1)
nd.node.conceptnode.myFunction()
```

... because Node is a parent to ConceptNode, so it can have many of them related. In fact I'd think you'd get an attribute error with `nd.node.conceptnode`. I think you'd access those child ConceptNodes via something like:

```
nd = NodeData.objects.get(id = 1)
nd.node.nodeParent.all() # Loop through this and do stuff with the children...
```

I'm using 'nodeParent' here since you've set the `related_name` (you might want to change it to something more fitting, like 'nodeChildren' or something), but by default it would be 'conceptnode_set', e.g.: `nd.node.conceptnode_set.all()`

If you're using Django 1.4, there's a new QuerySet method called `[prefetch_related][1]`, which I haven't used, but it's supposedly for this exact situation (cutting down queries for 'many'-type relationships), and you should theoretically be able to do something like:

```
nd = NodeData.objects.get(id = 1).prefetch_related('conceptnode')
```

... though you'll have to play with the 'conceptnode' argument, and with prefetch_related in general to see if it gets you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I think my question may have been confusing because both you and @chris-platt interpreted it the same way.  I do not need to fetch all children of a specific node, I just want to pre-fetch the DerivedNode or ConceptNode instance if a Node is also a ConceptNode or DerivedNode.

Comment: The problem is that there's no way to know what subclass of `Node` it is until *after* it's already been fetch from the database and all the classes are instantiated. Which is why you `select_related` all possibilities, and then the appropriate one will be there when you need it.

Comment: @chris-platt, you're exactly right.  That's why I'm referencing both derivednode and conceptnode in the solution.